# Proper values for innerHTML and translate Angular

Tags: angular, innerhtml, angular-translate

In translate json i have something like this

```
"Take": "The '<b>{{Name}}</b>' is assigned to user <b>{{user}}</b> until <b>{{Date}}</b>"
```

But when i try something like this in html

```
<p [innerHTML]="'Take' | translate: '{ Name: options.Name, user: options.user, Date: options.date }'">
</p>
```

And object

```
options = {
Name: John,
user: Rambo,
Date: 22/02/1997
}
```

I got this error
**ERROR SyntaxError: Wrong parameter in TranslatePipe. Expected a valid Object, received:**
I dont know where I am taking this wrong?

Comment: <p innerHTML="{{'Take' | translate: {' Name': options.Name, 'user': options.user, 'Date': options.date } }}">
</p>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
translate: '{ Name: options.Name, user: options.user, Date: options.date }'
```

Means your sending a string.

Try with

```
translate: { Name: options.Name, user: options.user, Date: options.date }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p [innerHTML]="'Take' | translate: { Name: options.Name, user: options.user, Date: options.date }">
```

is the right syntax.

I was confused with it sometimes too. Below is a more complicated usage case. Share here, in the case later you may need.

```
[attr.aria-label]="(_variable1$ | async) ? ('translateVariable' | translate: { translateProperty: _variable2 }) : ''"
```